# any html/css parsing library for ruby & PHP?

Tags: php, ruby, parsing, rubygems, screen-scraping

I am about to finish my script that parses/scrapes website using mechanize&ruby.

I need to port my script to PHP in the future.

My question is

- if there is any library available for both ruby and php or
- if anybody can recommend any other approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no PHP equivalent of Ruby and Mechanize.

However, Zend_Framework offers some great scraping-related libraries including

- Zend_URI and Zend_HTTP_Client
- [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html)

Answer (score 1):

As standard, PHP comes with several tools for parsing XML (and the DOM one can cope with a lot of badly formed HTML)

See

https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

C.

Answer (score 1):

For DOM manipulation in PHP use the [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Simple and easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Another DOM manipulation tool for php is [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).